# How to create folder in document library in Sharepoint using Adobe Flex3

Tags: apache-flex, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, flex3

i need to create a folder and subfolder dynamically in SharePoint list using Adobe Flex3. I haven't get much information in google to achieve this task.. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SharePoint Web Services API. You can find documentation on the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

For your specific request, in order to create a folder you need to use the `UpdateListItems` method, by passing it the following XML:

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" PreCalc="TRUE" 
ListVersion="0" 
ViewName="{EF2F5A21-0FD0-4654-84ED-112B4F5A48F8}">
   <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
      <Field Name="ID">New</Field>
      <Field Name="FSObjType">1</Field>
      <Field Name="BaseName">Name</Field>
   </Method>
</Batch>
```

Refer to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for other usage examples.